# M/M/1 queue implemenation using NS3

Tags: ns-3

How to implement the M/M/1 queue model using NS3. I need it for the p2p simulation. Any reference or source code would also work. Or are there any other simulators to model M/M/1 queues?

Answer (score 0):

There is no M/M/1 queue example in the ns-3 mainline, but I have written one as a course lab exercise.  See section IV of Lab 1 at https://depts.washington.edu/funlab/resources/ee-595-wireless-networks-for-4g5g/.  The code corresponding to this is at https://gitlab.com/tomhenderson/ns-3-ee-595 (checkout the 'course' branch).